# Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion Licensing

Tags: macos, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use the new Lion OS X license on two machines, or do I have to buy one for each?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17884/can-i-use-the-new-lion-os-x-license-on-two-machines-or-do-i-have-to-buy-one-for)

I have a few users that work with me that needed to reload Mountain Lion on their laptops. They had no connectivity so I let them borrow my bootable thumb drive.

Other than trusting their word.. What happens if they didn't actually buy a copy of ML? Does that mean that I violated my agreement?

I read more about the agreement here:

http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/26/install-upgrade-os-x-mountain-lion-multiple-macs/

More specifically this:

> *“(i) to download, install, use, and run for personal, non-commercial use, one (1) copy of the Apple Software directly on each Apple-branded computer running OS X Lion or OS X Snow Leopard (“Mac computer”) that you own or control.”*

Comment: Also this should help if the first question wasn't helpful.. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68493/how-many-copies-of-mountain-lion-does-one-app-store-download-get-me

Comment: I don't agree that this is an exact duplicate. My question is: how can I verify that someone has a license if they do not have connectivity? I'm being a good samaritan and providing them a physical copy of the software... Should I never provide other people with a copy then?